# Amplify iOS Login Screen Not Rendering Controls

Tags: ios, aws-amplify

I'm working with AWS Amplify on iOS to utilize the out of the box user authentication screens but unfortunately they are not fully rendering as shown below.  I am using the code from the Amplify tutorial at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-sign-in.html.  I'm using XCode 10 and I've tried numerous device emulators on v12 and v11.4 of iOS and they have all exhibited the same behavior.  Has anyone else experienced this scenario?  My code is included below:

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '12.0'

target 'TestApp1' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for TestApp1
  pod 'AWSCore', '~> 2.6.33'
  pod 'AWSPinpoint', '~> 2.6.33'
  pod 'AWSMobileClient', '~> 2.6.33'
  pod 'AWSUserPoolsSignIn', '~> 2.6.33'
  pod 'AWSAuthUI', '~> 2.6.33'

end
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import AWSPinpoint
import AWSMobileClient

...

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Create AWSMobileClient to connect with AWS
        return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                     sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {

        return AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance().interceptApplication(
            application, open: url,
            sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
            annotation: annotation)

    }
```

**View code from where I try to launch the sign in screen**

```
import AWSCore
import AWSMobileClient
import AWSAuthCore
import AWSAuthUI

...

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    showSignIn()
}

func showSignIn() {
    if !AWSSignInManager.sharedInstance().isLoggedIn {
        AWSAuthUIViewController
            .presentViewController(with: self.navigationController!,
                                   configuration: nil,
                                   completionHandler: { (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                                    if error != nil {
                                        print("Error occurred: \(String(describing: error))")
                                    } else {
                                        print("Identity provider: \(provider.identityProviderName)")
                                    }
            })
    }
}
```

[image: Screen Print of Emulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question got answered for me on GitHub at https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1082 by a gentleman named rohandubal.  The problem was that my awsconfiguration.json file did not have configuration information for CognitoUserPool.